# How can I save to avi file the captured streaming video in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, video, directshow, directshow.net

This is the cpp file content:

```
// VideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "VideoCaptureFilterSample.h"
#include "VideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg dialog




CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg::CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg, CDialog)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_PROPERTIES, &CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg::OnBnClickedProperties)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg message handlers

BOOL CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    InitGraph();

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialog::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}

void CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg::OnBnClickedProperties()
{
    ShowProperties();
}

void CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg::OnOK()
{
    HRESULT hr = DestroyGraph();
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    CDialog::OnOK();
}

void CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg::OnCancel()
{
    HRESULT hr = DestroyGraph();
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    CDialog::OnCancel();
}


/*=============================================================================
// BUILD GRAPH
=============================================================================*/


#include <initguid.h>
#include <streams.h>    // for DirectShow headers
#include <wmcodecdsp.h> // for MEDIASUBTYPE_MPEG_ADTS_AAC
#include <mmreg.h>      // for WAVE_FORMAT_MPEG_ADTS_AAC
#include <dvdmedia.h>   // for VIDEOINFOHEADER2
#include <bdaiface.h>   // for IMPEG2PIDMap

#pragma comment(lib, "strmbaseu.lib")       // for <streams.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wmcodecdspuuid.lib")  // for UUIDs from <wmcodecdsp.h>

#if 1
    #include "../VideoCaptureFilter/IVideoCaptureFilter.h"
#else
    #define ELGATO_VCF_VIDEO_PID    100 //!< video PID in MPEG-TS stream
    #define ELGATO_VCF_AUDIO_PID    101 //!< audio PID in MPEG-TS stream

    // Filter guid of Elgato Video Capture Filter
    // {39F50F4C-99E1-464a-B6F9-D605B4FB5918}
    DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_ElgatoVideoCaptureFilter, 
    0x39f50f4c, 0x99e1, 0x464a, 0xb6, 0xf9, 0xd6, 0x5, 0xb4, 0xfb, 0x59, 0x18);
#endif

// renderFromMpegTsPin: true  - use compressed data from the MPEG-TS pin (if present)
//                      false - use raw data from the video and audio pins
const bool renderFromMpegTsPin = false;



#ifndef SAFE_RELEASE
#define SAFE_RELEASE(_pI_) { if(_pI_) { (_pI_)->Release(); (_pI_)=NULL;} }
#endif


CComPtr<ICaptureGraphBuilder2>  pCapBuilder;
CComPtr<IFilterGraph2>          pFilterGraph;
CComPtr<IMediaControl>          pMediaControl;
CComPtr<IVideoWindow>           pVideoWindow;
CComPtr<IBasicAudio>            pBasicAudio;
CComPtr<IBaseFilter>            pCapFilter;

//! see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757808(v=vs.85).aspx
AM_MEDIA_TYPE* GetVideoMediaType()
{
    static VIDEOINFOHEADER2 vih;
    ZeroMemory(&vih, sizeof(vih));

    vih.bmiHeader.biSize            = sizeof(vih.bmiHeader);
    vih.bmiHeader.biWidth           = 1920;
    vih.bmiHeader.biHeight          = 1080;
    vih.bmiHeader.biPlanes          = 1;
    vih.bmiHeader.biBitCount        = 16;
    vih.bmiHeader.biCompression     = MAKEFOURCC('H', '2', '6', '4');

    vih.dwPictAspectRatioX          = 16;
    vih.dwPictAspectRatioY          = 9;

    static AM_MEDIA_TYPE  mt;
    ZeroMemory(&mt, sizeof(mt));

    mt.majortype                    = MEDIATYPE_Video;
    mt.subtype                      = MEDIASUBTYPE_H264;

    mt.bFixedSizeSamples            = FALSE;
    mt.bTemporalCompression         = TRUE;
    mt.lSampleSize                  = 1;

    mt.formattype                   = FORMAT_VideoInfo2;
    mt.cbFormat                     = sizeof(vih);
    mt.pbFormat                     = (BYTE*)&vih;

    return &mt;
}

//! @return audio media type that is accepted by "Microsoft DTV-DVD Audio Decoder"
AM_MEDIA_TYPE* GetAudioMediaType()
{
    static WAVEFORMATEX wfx;
    ZeroMemory(&wfx, sizeof(wfx));

    wfx.wFormatTag                  = WAVE_FORMAT_MPEG_ADTS_AAC;
    wfx.nChannels                   = 2;
    wfx.nSamplesPerSec              = 48000;
    wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec             = 14000;
    wfx.nBlockAlign                 = 24;
    wfx.wBitsPerSample              = 16;
    wfx.cbSize                      = 0;

    static AM_MEDIA_TYPE  mt;
    ZeroMemory(&mt, sizeof(mt));
    mt.majortype                    = MEDIATYPE_Audio;
    mt.subtype                      = MEDIASUBTYPE_MPEG_ADTS_AAC;

    mt.bFixedSizeSamples            = TRUE;
    mt.bTemporalCompression         = FALSE;
    mt.lSampleSize                  = 1;

    mt.formattype                   = FORMAT_WaveFormatEx;
    mt.cbFormat                     = sizeof(wfx);
    mt.pbFormat                     = (BYTE*)&wfx;

    return &mt;
}

void _DumpGraph(IFilterGraph2* pIFilterGraph)
{
    _ASSERTE(NULL != pIFilterGraph);
    if (NULL != pIFilterGraph)
    {
        CComPtr<IEnumFilters> pEnumFilters;
        HRESULT hrTmp = pFilterGraph->EnumFilters(&pEnumFilters);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hrTmp))
        {
            IBaseFilter* pFilter = NULL;
            while (S_OK == pEnumFilters->Next(1, &pFilter, NULL))
            {
                FILTER_INFO filterInfo;
                memset(&filterInfo, 0, sizeof(filterInfo));
                pFilter->QueryFilterInfo(&filterInfo);
                SAFE_RELEASE(filterInfo.pGraph);

                SAFE_RELEASE(pFilter);

                OutputDebugStringA("  Filter: ");
                OutputDebugStringW(filterInfo.achName);
                OutputDebugStringA("\n");

            }
        }
    }
}

HRESULT CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg::InitGraph()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Create the graph builder & filter graph
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // FMB NOTE: This is pretty safe, so we can assume it will not fail
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2, (void **)&pCapBuilder);
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IFilterGraph2, (void **)&pFilterGraph);
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    hr = pCapBuilder->SetFiltergraph(pFilterGraph);
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    hr = pFilterGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void**)&pMediaControl);
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Build graph
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    // Add "Elgato Game Capture HD" filter
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ElgatoVideoCaptureFilter, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&pCapFilter);
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    hr = pFilterGraph->AddFilter(pCapFilter, L"Elgato Game Capture HD");
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    // Add "Video Mixing Renderer 9" filter (VMR-9)
    CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pVideoRendererFilter;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoMixingRenderer9, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&pVideoRendererFilter);
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    hr = pFilterGraph->AddFilter(pVideoRendererFilter, L"VMR-9");
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    // Add Audio Renderer filter (must be in the graph as reference clock even if it is not connected)
    CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pAudioRendererFilter;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DSoundRender, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&pAudioRendererFilter);
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    hr = pFilterGraph->AddFilter(pAudioRendererFilter, L"DirectSound Renderer");
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // a) Render from MPEG-TS pin (if available)
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    CComPtr<IPin> pMpegTsOutput;
    HRESULT hrTmp = pCapBuilder->FindPin(pCapFilter, PINDIR_OUTPUT, NULL, &MEDIATYPE_Stream, TRUE, 0, &pMpegTsOutput);
    bool hasMpegTsPin = SUCCEEDED(hrTmp); // Elgato note: older versions of the capture filter don't have an MPEG-TS pin

    if (hasMpegTsPin && renderFromMpegTsPin)
    {
        // Add Microsoft Demultiplexer filter
        CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pDemultiplexerFilter;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MPEG2Demultiplexer, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&pDemultiplexerFilter);
        _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

        hr = pFilterGraph->AddFilter(pDemultiplexerFilter, L"MS Demux");
        _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

        // Configure Microsoft Demultiplexer filter
        CComPtr<IPin> pVideoPin;
        CComPtr<IPin> pAudioPin;
        {
            CComPtr<IMpeg2Demultiplexer> pIDemultiplexer;
            hr = pDemultiplexerFilter->QueryInterface(IID_IMpeg2Demultiplexer, (void**)&pIDemultiplexer);
            _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

            // Add video pin
            {
                hr = pIDemultiplexer->CreateOutputPin(GetVideoMediaType(), L"H.264", &pVideoPin);
                _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

                CComPtr<IMPEG2PIDMap> pIPidMap;
                hr = pVideoPin->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IMPEG2PIDMap), (void**)&pIPidMap);
                _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

                ULONG pid = ELGATO_VCF_VIDEO_PID;
                hr = pIPidMap->MapPID(1, &pid, MEDIA_ELEMENTARY_STREAM);
                _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
            }

            // Add audio pin
            {
                hr = pIDemultiplexer->CreateOutputPin(GetAudioMediaType(), L"AAC", &pAudioPin);
                _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

                CComPtr<IMPEG2PIDMap> pIPidMap;
                hr = pAudioPin->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IMPEG2PIDMap), (void**)&pIPidMap);
                _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

                ULONG pid = ELGATO_VCF_AUDIO_PID;
                hr = pIPidMap->MapPID(1, &pid, MEDIA_ELEMENTARY_STREAM);
                _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
            }
        }

        // Connect filters
        CComPtr<IPin> pDemultiplexerInput;
        hr = pCapBuilder->FindPin(pDemultiplexerFilter, PINDIR_INPUT, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, &pDemultiplexerInput);
        _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

        hr = pFilterGraph->Connect(pMpegTsOutput, pDemultiplexerInput);
        _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

        hr = pCapBuilder->RenderStream(NULL, &MEDIATYPE_Video, pVideoPin, NULL, pVideoRendererFilter);
        _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

        hr = pCapBuilder->RenderStream(NULL, &MEDIATYPE_Audio, pAudioPin, NULL, pAudioRendererFilter);
        _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    }
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // b) Render from audio and video pins
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    else
    {
        hr = pCapBuilder->RenderStream(NULL, &MEDIATYPE_Video, pCapFilter, NULL, pVideoRendererFilter);
        _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

        hr = pCapBuilder->RenderStream(NULL, &MEDIATYPE_Audio, pCapFilter, NULL, pAudioRendererFilter);
        _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Set audio renderer as reference clock for the graph
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        CComPtr<IReferenceClock> pRefClock;
        hr = pAudioRendererFilter->QueryInterface(IID_IReferenceClock, (void**)&pRefClock);
        _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
        CComPtr<IMediaFilter> pMediaFilter;
        hr = pFilterGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaFilter, (void**)&pMediaFilter);
        _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
        hr = pMediaFilter->SetSyncSource(pRefClock);
        _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

#if 1
        // TS WORKAROUND 15-Aug-11: Avoid cracking noise after graph is started 
        // by increasing the error tolerance of the Audio Renderer from 20ms to 200ms
        CComPtr<IAMClockSlave> pIAMClockSlave;
        HRESULT hrTmp = pAudioRendererFilter->QueryInterface(IID_IAMClockSlave, (void**)&pIAMClockSlave);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hrTmp))
            hrTmp = pIAMClockSlave->SetErrorTolerance(200);
        _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hrTmp));
#endif
    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Playback
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // set video window
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pFilterGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IVideoWindow, (void**)&pVideoWindow);
        _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));


        CWnd* pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_VIDEOWINDOW);
        CRect rcClient;
        pWnd->GetClientRect(&rcClient);

        hr = pVideoWindow->put_Owner((OAHWND)pWnd->m_hWnd);
        _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

        pVideoWindow->put_WindowStyleEx(0);
        pVideoWindow->put_WindowStyle(WS_CHILD);
        pVideoWindow->SetWindowPosition(0, 0, rcClient.Width(), rcClient.Height());

        void SaveVideoToFile(int hr);
        SaveVideoToFile(hr);
    }

    // play
    hr = pMediaControl->Run();
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    // set volume to maximum
    hr = pFilterGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IBasicAudio, (void**)&pBasicAudio);
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    hr = pBasicAudio->put_Volume(0);
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr)); 

#ifdef _DEBUG   // Dump graph
    _DumpGraph(pFilterGraph);
#endif

    return hr;
}

HRESULT CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg::DestroyGraph()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;

    _ASSERTE(NULL != pMediaControl);
    hr = pMediaControl->Stop();
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));


    // Elgato note: This may take a few seconds
    _ASSERTE(NULL != pFilterGraph);
    hr = pFilterGraph->RemoveFilter(pCapFilter);
    _ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg::ShowProperties()
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    if(NULL != pCapFilter)
    {
        CComPtr<ISpecifyPropertyPages> pSpec;
        hr = pCapFilter->QueryInterface(IID_ISpecifyPropertyPages, (void **) &pSpec);
        if (hr == S_OK) 
        {
            CAUUID  cauuid;
            hr = pSpec->GetPages(&cauuid);
            if (hr == S_OK && cauuid.cElems > 0)
            {
                IBaseFilter* pFilter = pCapFilter;
                hr = OleCreatePropertyFrame(NULL,40, 40, NULL, 1,(IUnknown **)&pFilter, 
                    cauuid.cElems,(GUID *)cauuid.pElems, 0, 0, NULL);
                CoTaskMemFree(cauuid.pElems);
            }
        }
    }
    return hr;
}

void SaveVideoToFile(int hr)
{

    IBaseFilter *pMux;
    hr = pCapBuilder->SetOutputFileName(
        &MEDIASUBTYPE_Avi,  // Specifies AVI for the target file.
        L"E:\\Example.avi", // File name.
        &pMux,              // Receives a pointer to the mux.
        NULL);

    hr = pCapBuilder->RenderStream(
        &PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, // Pin category.
        &MEDIATYPE_Video,      // Media type.
        pCapFilter,                  // Capture filter.
        NULL,                  // Intermediate filter (optional).
        pMux);                 // Mux or file sink filter.

                               // Release the mux filter.
    pMux->Release();

    IConfigAviMux *pConfigMux = NULL;
    hr = pMux->QueryInterface(IID_IConfigAviMux, (void**)&pConfigMux);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        pConfigMux->SetMasterStream(1);
        pConfigMux->Release();
    }

    IConfigInterleaving *pInterleave = NULL;
    hr = pMux->QueryInterface(IID_IConfigInterleaving, (void**)&pInterleave);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        pInterleave->put_Mode(INTERLEAVE_CAPTURE);
        pInterleave->Release();
    }

    IBaseFilter *pEncoder;
    //Create the encoder filter (not shown).
    // Add it to the filter graph.
    pFilterGraph->AddFilter(pEncoder, L"Encoder");

    //Call SetOutputFileName as shown previously.

    // Render the stream.
    hr = pCapBuilder->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video,
    pCapFilter,
    pEncoder, pMux);
    pEncoder->Release();
}
```

This is the method I'm trying to save the video to a avi file. The example is from the [MSDN document site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318627(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
void SaveVideoToFile(int hr)
{

    IBaseFilter *pMux;
    hr = pCapBuilder->SetOutputFileName(
        &MEDIASUBTYPE_Avi,  // Specifies AVI for the target file.
        L"E:\\Example.avi", // File name.
        &pMux,              // Receives a pointer to the mux.
        NULL);

    hr = pCapBuilder->RenderStream(
        &PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, // Pin category.
        &MEDIATYPE_Video,      // Media type.
        pCapFilter,                  // Capture filter.
        NULL,                  // Intermediate filter (optional).
        pMux);                 // Mux or file sink filter.

                               // Release the mux filter.
    pMux->Release();

    IConfigAviMux *pConfigMux = NULL;
    hr = pMux->QueryInterface(IID_IConfigAviMux, (void**)&pConfigMux);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        pConfigMux->SetMasterStream(1);
        pConfigMux->Release();
    }

    IConfigInterleaving *pInterleave = NULL;
    hr = pMux->QueryInterface(IID_IConfigInterleaving, (void**)&pInterleave);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        pInterleave->put_Mode(INTERLEAVE_CAPTURE);
        pInterleave->Release();
    }

    IBaseFilter *pEncoder;
    //Create the encoder filter (not shown).
    // Add it to the filter graph.
    pFilterGraph->AddFilter(pEncoder, L"Encoder");

    //Call SetOutputFileName as shown previously.

    // Render the stream.
    hr = pCapBuilder->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video,
    pCapFilter,
    pEncoder, pMux);
    pEncoder->Release();
}
```

And I'm calling it like this in the bottom of the set video window part:

```
void SaveVideoToFile(int hr);
SaveVideoToFile(hr);
```

Now I'm getting error since in the `SaveVideoToFile` I didn't initialized
 the `pEncoder`.

The error:

> The variable 'pEncoder' is being used without being initialized

If not using the pEncoder it does nothing no errors but it's saving anything to avi file.

This is the example I'm using from Microsoft MSDN site:

[Capturing Video to an AVI File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318627(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: **"i'm getting error since in the SaveVideoToFile i didn't initialized the pEncoder"**, which, i guess, means you already know what the problem is. So why not initialize the uninitialized variable then.

Comment: bkVnet right I forgot to mention that i'm not sure how to initialized it. Tried to google for exmaples but didn't find.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The example code is clear about the `pEncoder` variable, "not shown":

```
IBaseFilter *pEncoder;
//Create the encoder filter (not shown). <<-------- 
// Add it to the filter graph.
pFilterGraph->AddFilter(pEncoder, L"Encoder");
```

Not shown means that this initialization is omitted for code brevity. MSDN article for [Choosing a Compression Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374572) is somewhat outdated, along with AVI format, but eventually it is you who are responsible to arrange compression of your video stream and hence choose encoder filter, add it to the filter graph. You might want to try for starters [MJPEG Compressor Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390690), which is a stock filter.

Comment: Roman a question, If i'm not using a the pEncoder at all wasn't it suppose to create avi file with video uncompressed ? And the place i'm calling the method SaveVideoToFile is right ?

Comment: Uncompressed is in most cases not what you want, but you can try. The line with `IBaseFilter *pEncoder` should be `IBaseFilter *pEncoder = NULL;` Comment out the following AddFilter line, and then `pEncoder->Release` too.

Comment: I did // on the lines AddFilter and the Release so it will not use them. And I set the *pEncoder to NULL; but still the file on the hard disk is empty 0 KB and when I quit the program it's deleting the file.